# Opposite attribute to compare attribute in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, compare-attribute

Can i have a not compare attribute which is opposite to compare attribute in asp.net mvc. I am developing a reset password application. I have used a compare attribute for new password and confirm password. I want to check if the current password and the new password are not same. How can i do this on the client side itself. Pleae help.

Comment: [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) have a `[NotEqualTo]` validation attribute that may suit your needs.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I get an error when [NotEqualTo] is written. It is not recognizing. Am i missing any reference.?

Comment: Have you installed the foolproof nuget package?